# How can i move my objects on the screen randomly on Corona?

Tags: object, move, coronasdk

I want my display objects to move on the screen with a velocity and without any interactions. How can i do that with corona? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to add your display object to the physics, and then set its velocity to a random value. You can use a timer to periodically change the movement of the display object. For example:

```
physics = require("physics");
physics.start()
rectangle = display.newRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
physics.addBody(rectangle, "kinematic", {isSensor = true})
function moveRandomly()
rectangle:setLinearVelocity(math.random(-300,300), math.random(-300,300));
end
timer.performWithDelay(500, moveRandomly, -1);
```